# Angular JS Application Failed to Retrieve Data From Sql Database Though Wcf Service

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, rest, wcf

I am consuming Wcf Rest Service into Angular JS Application. I am trying to retrieve a single record from Sql database though Wcf Rest Service. The Wcf Service able to post the to Angular JS Application but When i click the submit button in site i do not found the record in Angular js Application .I checked in Google Chrome Network tab ,there I found the that particular  record.

Here is the Interface .

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    UriTemplate = "/GetCustomers/{Account_Holder_Last_Name}")]
    string GetCustomers(string Account_Holder_Last_Name);
```

Here is Implementation of Interface .

```
public string GetCustomers(string Account_Holder_Last_Name)
    {

        List<object> customers = new List<object>();
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM Current_Account_Holder_Details WHERE Account_Holder_Last_Name =@Account_Holder_Last_Name";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Account_Holder_Last_Name", Account_Holder_Last_Name);
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (sdr.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (sdr.Read())
                        {

                            customers.Add(new
                            {
                                Tittle = sdr["Tittle"],
                                Account_Holder_First_Name = sdr["Account_Holder_First_Name"],
                                Account_Holder_Last_Name = sdr["Account_Holder_Last_Name"],
                                Account_Holder_DOB = sdr["Account_Holder_DOB"],
                                Account_Holder_House_No = sdr["Account_Holder_House_No"],
                                Account_Holder_Street_Name = sdr["Account_Holder_Street_Name"],
                                Account_Holder_Post_Code = sdr["Account_Holder_Post_Code"],

                                Account_Holder_Occupation = sdr["Account_Holder_Occupation"],
                                Account_Number = sdr["Account_Number"]



                            });
                        }

                    }

                }
                conn.Close();
            }

            return (new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(customers));
        }

    }
```

Here is the HTML Code with Angular JS Script code  .

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module('MyApp', [])
        app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $http, $window) {
            $scope.IsVisible = false;
            $scope.Search = function () {
                var post = $http({
                    method: "GET",
                    url: "http://localhost:52098/HalifaxIISService.svc/GetCustomers/" + encodeURIComponent($scope.Account_Holder_Last_Name),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                    }
                });

                post.success(function (data, status) {
                    $scope.Customers = eval(data.d);
                    $scope.IsVisible = true;
                },
                    function (err) {
                        console.log("Some Error Occured." + err);
                    }
                );

                post.error(function (data, status) {
                    $window.alert(data.Message);
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
    <div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
        Name:
        <input type="text" ng-model="Account_Holder_Last_Name" />
        <input type="button" value="Submit" ng-click="Search()" />
        <hr />
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" ng-show="IsVisible">
            <tr style="height: 30px; background-color: skyblue; color: maroon;">
                <th> Tittle</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th> Last Name</th>
                <th>  DOB </th>
                <th> House No</th>
                <th> Street Name</th>
                <th>Post Code</th>
                <th> Occupation</th>
                <th>Account Number</th>


            </tr>
            <tbody ng-repeat="m in Customers">
                <tr>
                    <td>{{m.Tittle}}</td>
                    <td>{{m.Account_Holder_First_Name}}</td>
                    <td>{{m.Account_Holder_Last_Name}}</td>

                    <td>{{m.Account_Holder_DOB}}</td>
                    <td>{{m.Account_Holder_House_No}}</td>
                    <td>{{m.Account_Holder_Street_Name}}</td>
                    <td>{{m.Account_Holder_Post_Code}}</td>

                    <td>{{m.Account_Holder_Occupation}}</td>
                    <td>{{m.Account_Number}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the Result when i run the application on Network Tab ..
[image]

Comment: Can you include the response in your post as well?

Comment: You can check the screen shot

Comment: For security reasons, it is safer to use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) instead of [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval).

Comment: Ok. Thanks what other changes I have make

Comment: Use [console.log](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) statements to debug the code.

Comment: i updated question i did not found any error

Comment: I am can not wondering where the excetly problem is ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't really set this up in my local. But what I suggested is just a simple change as shown below, just adding **$scope.Customers = [];** at the top.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('MyApp', [])
    app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $http, $window) {
        $scope.IsVisible = false;
        $scope.Customers = [];
        $scope.Search = function () {
            var post = $http({
                method: "GET",
                url: "http://localhost:52098/HalifaxIISService.svc/GetCustomers/" + encodeURIComponent($scope.Account_Holder_Last_Name),
                dataType: 'json',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                }
            });

            post.success(function (data, status) {
                $scope.Customers = eval(data.d);
                $scope.IsVisible = true;
            },
                function (err) {
                    console.log("Some Error Occured." + err);
                }
            );

            post.error(function (data, status) {
                $window.alert(data.Message);
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly - the service is returning data, but the UI is not rendering it.

I don't see "Customers" object defined. Also you can add a "debugger" statement in the "post.success" and "post.error" methods to see where exactly the issue is coming up. It shows up the exceptions clearly.

Just add the debugger statement and F12 in your browser.
Hope that helps you to figure out the problem.

Regards
Neelima

Comment: on post.success function i defined the customers object .but if you say its not defined where i have to make the changes

Comment: Its says local host undefined

Comment: Where I have to define??

Comment: I guess u will have to define it outside the function as well in order to access it in your HTML code.  Under $scope.IsVisible = false, u can define $scope.Customers = [] (if that's an array object).